# LMarker (leaflet) in vuejs3 causing error

Tags: leaflet, vuejs3

I use Leaflet components in my project but as I use LMarker component and it prints out error as I touch the marker. I use  "leaflet": "^1.6.0", "@vue-leaflet/vue-leaflet": "^0.10.1", "@types/leaflet": "^1.5.7",

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQxej.png)

```
<div v-for="marker in markers" :key="marker.id">
    <LMarker
      :lat-lng="marker.coordinates"
      :draggable="editMode"
      @dragend="
        (e) => {
          markerDragend(e, marker)
        }
      "
      @click="
        () => {
          if (isMobileMode) {
            markerOnClick(marker)
          } else {
            markerPress(marker)
          }
        }
      "
    >
      <LIcon
        :icon-url="getIconUrlByName(marker.icon)"
        :iconAnchor="[30, 70]"
        :popupAnchor="[0, -35]"
        :tooltipAnchor="[0, -20]"
        :class-name="marker.className"
      /></LMarker></div>
```